# Access PostgreSQL on Mac without switching users

Tags: osx-lion, file-permissions, user, postgresql

I've got a Mac running OS X Lion (10.7.5), with PostgreSQL 9.2.4 installed.  I've initialized a database cluster and started a server, all as the `postgres` user.  When I try to access certain directories related to my PostgreSQL installation, or execute certain binaries, I need to switch to the `postgres` user first.  For instance:

```
# Ideally I'd want this to work:
my_name$ psql
psql: FATAL:  role "my_name" does not exist

# I'd settle for this working, but it doesn't
my_name$ sudo psql
psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist

# I don't understand why this doesn't work but the next things does
my_name$ sudo su postgres psql
/opt/local/lib/postgresql92/bin/psql: /opt/local/lib/postgresql92/bin/psql: cannot execute binary file

# This works
my_name$ sudo su postgres
sh$ psql
psql (9.2.4)
Type "help" for help.
```

Another example:

```
my_name$ cd /opt/local/var/db/postgresql92/defaultdb
-bash: cd: /opt/local/var/db/postgresql92/defaultdb/: Permission denied

my_name$ sudo su postgres cd /opt/local/var/db/postgresql92/defaultdb
my_name$ pwd
/Users/my_name

my_name$ sudo su postgres
sh$ cd /opt/local/var/db/postgresql92/defaultdb
sh$ pwd
/opt/local/var/db/postgresql92/defaultdb
```

1. Why does `sudo su postgres <cmd>` not work, but when I separate the steps of switching the user and then invoking the command, it does work?
2. Is there another way around this so that I don't have to switch users every time?
3. More generally, is there a way to give a user all the permissions of another user in addition to the ones it already has?  E.g. can I add all of the `postgres` user's permissions to the `my_name` user's permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You must have a user created in your postgresql database and allow it from localhost in your pg_hba.conf file - plenty of examples in the file on the various options.

Then you can do:

psql -H localhost -U myuser